# Wynn-epsilon convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, convergence-acceleration

How could I use the Wynn-epsilon alghoritm in Matlab to accelerate the convergence of a Maclaurin series?

I want to extimate the first derivative of $f(x)$, so

$$f'(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty {ka_kx^{k-1}}$$

where $a_k$ is the coefficient

$$a_k=\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$$

The epsilon alghoritm is like

$\epsilon_{-1}^{(l)}=0 \\\epsilon_{0}^{(l)}=S_{l}(x) \ \ \ \ l=0,...,L \\\epsilon_{k+1}^{(l)}=\epsilon_{k-1}^{(l+1)}+\left[\epsilon_{k}^{(l+1)}-\epsilon_{k}^{(l-1)}\right]^{-1}  \ \ \ \  ,k=0,...,L; \ \ \ l=0,...,L-k-1.$

Where $S_{l}(x)$ is the succession of partial sums, i.e., in our case

$$S_{l}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^l {ka_kx^{k-1}}$$

Definitively we got a tableau from $\epsilon$ values like
$$ \begin{matrix}
\epsilon_0^{0} & \epsilon_1^{0} & \epsilon_2 ^{0} & \cdots & \epsilon_{L-1}^{0} & \epsilon_{L}^{0}\\ \epsilon_{0}^{1} & \epsilon_{1}^{1} & \epsilon_{2}^{1} &\cdots& \epsilon_{L-1}^{1}\\ \epsilon_{0}^{2} &\cdots & \\ \vdots \\ \ & \epsilon_{1}^{(L-1)}\\
\epsilon_{0}^{L}\end{matrix} $$

where each element of $\mathbf{even}$ columns extimates the limit. I tried to solve it, but i got many problems. I know it could be a not immediate question but i would really appreciate your help. I need this to solve Blasius and Falkner Scan problem. If you need any other information please ask me. Thanks in advance for any incoming comments!

EDIT $\\$

for Antonio Vargas $\\$

$f(x)$ is the function i get from the solution of Falkner Scan equation for boundary layer: 
$$f'''(x)+\beta_0 f(x)f''(x)+\beta (1-f'(x)^2)=0$$

The coefficients of the series are known since they are found by recurrence by applying the differential operator to the equation $$\frac{d^k}{dx^k}$$

You can see the results at page 4 and 5 of the pdf [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.3888.pdf). If you could look at it and tell me where does the $\delta_{k0}$ in the eq. (3) come from i would appreciate your help. For the Matlab problem of convergence I should probably post in the other section as the previous user suggested, maybe I have solved, but I have to finish and be sure before posting solution. Thanks for interesting and, if you want, for help.

Comment: "I tried to solve it, but i got many problems." Yes, but you haven't even told us what one of them is. Edit your question. Break this up to ask specific questions about specific issues. Don't expect people to wrap their heads around your entire problem at once. Also, if you're programming this, you might show your code. However, if the question is more about Matlab coding rather than the underlying math, then you should probably go to [StackOverflow/Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab).

Comment: What is $f(x)$?  Do you know the coefficients of the series?

Comment: Yes, I know them, even if it is not so immediate...I edited the question